# Access web.config settings from iisnode?

Tags: iisnode

If I add settings to my app's web.config file, is there an API to read the settings from my app or do I have to read the file using an XML library?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no special API that allows you read web.config into your node.js application running in iisnode. Having said that:

- all key/value pairs from the appSettings section in web.config will be promoted to environment variables of the node.exe process, so you can access them using process.env,
- as of iisnode v0.1.19, in addition to web.config, configuration settings can be specified in a iisnode.yml file; see http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2012/05/yaml-configuration-support-in-iisnode.html for details.

This example shows how promoted key/value pairs from the appSettings section in web.config are available as environment variables. In your web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="abc" value="test" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

In your node application: `console.log(process.env.abc); //--> test`

Comment: I have tried the solution above, yet console logs: undefined. Is there anything I may have missed in the project setup? Thank you

Comment: I tried the same solution and am getting "undefined" as well.  @tomasz-janczuk can you please update your answer or at least explain if there are any other settings that need to be in place?

Comment: same here; i get undefined when i add a key to appSettings and then try to access it via the process.env object (ex: process.env.abc fails). I don't see any other articles confirming the above statement.