# Accessing web.config appSettings in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, iis-7, iisnode

I am doing prototype with nodejs + expressjs that are hosted on IIS7. I am trying to access appSettings in web.config in app.js following sample from post:

[Access web.config settings from iisnode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809465/how-to-access-web-config-settings-from-iisnode)

Unfortunately, the sample from the post above logs "undefined" instead of the value "test". Is there anything else needs to be setup in web.congig or app.js in order to access web.config values?

I am using visual studio 2013 to run/debug the project, and there were no issues to run it. 
Thank you

Comment: What Visual Studio project type are you using?